# Connect to AWS Athena with JDBC driver when AWS access is given through (Azure) OIDC provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, openid-connect, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

We connect to AWS through our office365 users given to us by our company. Since we assume a role in the UI, how would I connect to Athena from a JDBC tool like DataGrip?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JDBC for Athena then you can have the connection string as shown below and your access key credentials as user name and password.

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.{REGION}.amazonaws.com:443
```

Or

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion={REGION}
```

Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/connect-to-aws-athena-using-datagrip-c34762e37a17) and [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Migration+Guide.pdf) which helps you in configuring the connection and run queries from DataGrip.

Answer (score 0):

Use "com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain". This class trying to load credential from different provider one by one until it get success.

More detail about Simba athena lib - [simba athena lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html)

Sample code for referene:

```
    PoolConfiguration configuration = ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) dataSource).getPoolProperties();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("S3OutputLocation", "s3://bucket-name/folder/");
    properties.setProperty("AwsCredentialsProviderClass", "com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain");
    configuration.setDbProperties(properties);
    JdbcTemplate template =  new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```